# Probability Distribution and Data Distribution in ML

Tags: machine-learning, math, statistics

I have been reading about probability distributions lately and got confused that what actually is the difference between probability distribution and data distribution or are they the same? Also what actually is the importance of probability distribution in Machine Learning?

Thanks

Comment: Interesting questions, but off topic for SO; try datascience.stackexchange.com or stats.stackexchange.com instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Data distribution** is a function or a listing that shows all the possible values (or intervals) of the data. This can help you decide if the set of good that you have is good enough to apply any techniques over it. You want to avoid skewed data.

**Probability distribution** is a statistical function that describes all the possible values and likelihoods that a random variable can take within a given range. This helps you decide what type of statistical methods you can apply to your data. **Example:** If your data forms a Gaussian distribution then you already know how values would look like when they are 1-standard deviation away from normal and what is the probability of expecting more than 1-standard deviation.

**NOTE**: You may want to learn about how hypothesis testing is done for ML models.